# Recommended Mathematics electives for Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm a Statistics and CS double major and I must take two more math electives to complete my degree.

I have four choices for the Math courses I could take and I was wondering which of the two would be most beneficial for Machine Learning or Artificial Intelligence.

My choices are:

(1) Combinatorics 1 (2nd year course, also I've already taken Discrete Mathematics)

(2) Mathematical Modelling (2nd year course)

(3) Numerical Analysis 1 (2nd year course)

(4)Linear Algebra and Matrix Analysis (4th year course - this would be my 3rd Linear Algebra class)

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @henry-l What is a [tag:soft-question]? Perhaps the tag [tag:references] would be more appropriate?!

Comment: @Henry.L Indeed, why create a new tag without a Wiki etc.?

Comment: Hi, I mistakenly thought this tag already exists since it is a tag on mathoverflow, thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you should take all four (or at least three of them). Otherwise, in order,

1. Numerical Analysis -- assuming that this doesn't mean real or
   complex analysis, but instead numerical computation
2. Mathematical Modeling -- always a good skill to have; will possibly lean more
   towards PDEs than statistical modeling
3. Linear Algebra and Matrix
   Analysis -- if you hadn't already taken two years this would be
   higher
4. Combinatorics -- While knowing combinatorics is important,
   the full class might go in less important directions (I could be wrong here)

Comment: Are these in order from least to most useful?

Comment: The order is most to least useful